# String comparison using "&&"

Tags: javascript

What would be the difference between the following:

```
.map((word) => word && '')
```

And

```
.map((word) => '')
```

Both of them seem to return same value.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()

Comment: If `word` is *falsey* the former would return `word` instead.